# Flutter conditional time statement

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to show up greeting text something like (Goodmorning,  Good afternoon,  Good evening) in a text widget between the times of 6 hours intervals in flutter

I've been trying to come out with how to...but still nothing so far. If someone can help me out with a code of such. Thanks

Comment: Present your best effort, with a minimal reproducible example.

Answer (score 2):

To add onto Naqeeb's answer, the latest version of Flutter ships with Dart 3 which comes with switch expressions. That means the chained if-then blocks:

```dart
DateTime now = DateTime.now();
if (now.hour >= 6 && now.hour < 12) {
  greeting = 'Good morning';
} else if (now.hour >= 12 && now.hour < 18) {
  greeting = 'Good afternoon';
} else {
  greeting = 'Good evening';
}
```

can be replaced with a pattern-powered switch block:

```dart
DateTime now = DateTime.now();
switch(now.hour) {
  case >= 6 && < 12    : greeting = 'Good morning';
  case >= 12 && < 18   : greeting = 'Good afternoon';
  default              : greeting = 'Good evening';
}
```

or better yet, a switch expression:

```dart
DateTime now = DateTime.now();
greeting = switch(now.hour) {
  >= 6 && < 12     => 'Good morning',
  >= 12 && < 18    => 'Good afternoon',
  _                => 'Good evening',
};
```

Comment: So how can I show it in a text widget

Comment: @KNGGEO Have `greeting` be a state variable in a `StatefulWidget` that you then pass to the `Text` widget. Or if you don't expect/want `greeting` to change dynamically (i.e. you just want to update the text every time the user opens the app), call this code in the `build` method itself.

Comment: ok sir - both works as expected

Answer (score 1):

You may use the DateTime.now() function to get the current time from user and depending on the value of that time you can update your greeting message by calling set state or using the corresponding method for your state management. You can apply if else conditions on the value obtained from DateTime.now() function.
Here's some example code that can help you.

```
void updateGreeting() {
setState(() {
  // Get the current system time
  DateTime now = DateTime.now();
  // Determine the appropriate greeting based on the time of day
  if (now.hour >= 6 && now.hour < 12) {
    greeting = 'Good morning';
  } else if (now.hour >= 12 && now.hour < 18) {
    greeting = 'Good afternoon';
  } else {
    greeting = 'Good evening';
  }
});

// Update the greeting every minute
Timer(Duration(minutes: 1), updateGreeting);
}
```